# how to let the slave to upload the build file to another remote server?

Tags: jenkins, scp, jenkins-plugins

I use Jenkins to trigger a slave to make a build,after the build finished,I want the slave to copy the build file to a master machine.I know there are scp plugin in the Jenkins,but is it work for the slave? how to configure it?
if this plugin doesn't work,is there any other solution?

Comment: Just archive the build file, it will be saved on master

Comment: Thanks, it is an easy way!

Comment: @ShivaKumar Is there a Jenkins plugin that can move files during the post build action period?

Comment: There are few that can publish files/artifacts over FTP. Check [Publish Over FTP Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin), [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you flag the file as an artifact to be archived in the post-build step, then it will be streamed back to the master.

Comment: Is there a Jenkins plugin that can move files during the post build action period?

Comment: If you want to put the file in another place on the filesystem of the master, then create another job just for that, and trigger it as post-build action of the first one. You can retrieve the artifacts from another build if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just did that.